# How to use NestJS (nest build) with typescript transformer plugins?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a custom Typescript transformer plugin in my project, which I used to invoke using the [ttypescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript) compiler. It did not need any special setup, other than adding it to the `plugins` array in `tsconfig.json`.

I'm trying to migrate to NestJS now and I am not sure how to make my plugin work when using `nest build`. I could skip using `nest build` and instead run `ttsc`, which does solve the problem, but then I'd also have to add a plugin for Typescript's path mapping, which NestJS seems to do out-of-the-box. I am also not sure what else I might be missing, as I trust `nest build` to be optimized for building NestJS applications.